# The error "There were multiply-defined labels" even though the label names are different

Tags: cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cref

I have recently encountered a beautiful LaTex [template](https://github.com/SeniorMars/dotfiles/tree/master/latex_template) for a lecture note.

[image]

I'm trying to adapt it to suit my needs. I compiled below tex template on overleaf and got warnings

```
Label `abc' multiply defined.
Label `abc@cref' multiply defined.
There were multiply-defined labels.
```

The names of the two labels are `proba` and `abc`, so they are different.

Could you elaborate on the reason of the warnings? Thank you so much for your elaboration!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[tmargin=2cm,rmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,margin=0.85in,bmargin=2cm,footskip=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[varbb]{newpxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref,theoremref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={Assignment},
    colorlinks=true, linkcolor=doc!90,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true
}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\definecolor{mytheorembg}{HTML}{F2F2F9}
\definecolor{mytheoremfr}{HTML}{00007B}
\definecolor{mydefinitbg}{HTML}{E5E5FF}
\definecolor{mydefinitfr}{HTML}{3F3FA3}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}


%================================
% THEOREM BOX
%================================
\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter, crefname={theorem}{Theorem}]{theorem}{Theorem}
{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback = mytheorembg,
    frame hidden,
    boxrule = 0sp,
    borderline west = {2pt}{0pt}{mytheoremfr},
    sharp corners,
    detach title,
    before upper = \tcbtitle\par\smallskip,
    coltitle = mytheoremfr,
    fonttitle = \bfseries\sffamily,
    description font = \mdseries,
    separator sign none,
    segmentation style={solid, mytheoremfr},
}{}

%================================
% DEFINITION BOX
%================================
\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter, crefname={definition}{Definition}]{definition}{Definition}{enhanced,
    before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm, colback=red!5,colframe=red!80!black,boxrule=0.5mm,
    attach boxed title to top left={xshift=1cm,yshift*=1mm-\tcboxedtitleheight}, varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
    boxed title style={frame code={
                    \path[fill=tcbcolback]
                    ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
                    arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1mm]
                    ([yshift=-1mm,xshift=1mm]frame.north east)
                    arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1mm];
                    \path[left color=tcbcolback!60!black,right color=tcbcolback!60!black,
                        middle color=tcbcolback!80!black]
                    ([xshift=-2mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=2mm]frame.north east)
                    [rounded corners=1mm]-- ([xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north east)
                    -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
                    -- ([xshift=-1mm,yshift=-1mm]frame.north west)
                    [sharp corners]-- cycle;
                },interior engine=empty,
        },
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={#2},#1}{def}



\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[label={proba}]{Ohlala}{}
xyz
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[label={abc}]{Markov chain}{}
abc
\end{definition}

Thanks to \Cref{proba} and \cref{abc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it is perfect: I have not any errors! It compiles fine. Have you updated your MikTeX distribuition or TeXlive?

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you so much for your reply! Actually, I run the code on overleaf.

Comment: You can try with https://www.papeeria.com/ and you can see that your code works correctly.

Comment: @Sebastiano You are right! Thank you so much again!

Comment: You're welcome .

Comment: @Sebastiano beware papeeria uses a [very old latex by default and at best a 2019 release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skfyu.png) so can't be used to test issues solved by updating texlivee

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Dear David, I wrote it at the beginning if the user had the updated LaTeX distributions. He wrote me that he uses overleaf. I simply have shown that up to 2019 papeeria does not give any problem. It is to see which recent engine Overleaf uses to compile. I don't know that.

Comment: Overleaf uses 2022 @Sebastiano

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not know this.